# Android Application doesn't run on Physical Device nor emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Hi I have been using Android Studio for a while now and it always run smoothly. But today after opening it after some days it doesn't run neither on the physical device nor on the emulator.

I have encountered the following error

12:30:04 Gradle build finished with 3 error(s) in 48s 714ms

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 46.376 secs

Comment: as said in the log, please run gradle with --stracktrace and post it

Comment: Fix your 3 errors. Look at the logs.